# Cordova - Safari iPhone remote inspection disconnects

Tags: ios, cordova, safari

I'm using the Safari Web Inspector to remote debug a Cordova app I'm building. Previously this has worked like a charm, but now I've run into an issue. After launching the inspector, after a couple of seconds it seems like the web inspector disconnects from the device. The inspector is still open, but the inspector wont update, and elements on the device wont be highlighted anymore when hovered in the inspector (this works for the first couple of seconds). I'm able to get it running for a couple of seconds again by closing the inspector and launching it again.

I've tried debugging using Chrome and `ios_webkit_debug_proxy` instead, which doesn't disconnect. However, this has other issues which makes it a none viable solution.

I've tried using Safari Technology Preview (11.0 R35) as well as the current stable version of Safari (10.1.2), but the issue occurs in both of them. I've also tried switching the lightning cable and USB-port on my computer, which doesn't make any difference.

I found that the following error is logged (using the Console app) when the inspector seems to disconnect:

```
RWIServiceLockdownConnection: Disconnecting because we failed to read a message from webinspectord. This could mean almost anything.
```

This does seem to have something to do with Cordova, since the error doesn't occur when I inspect a regular page Mobile Safari page.

What could cause this, and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Do you use a web worker in your javascript? If so, that is an known Safari issue.

Comment: @Joerg no I don't, so that shouldn't be an issue!

Comment: I had the same problem. My solution was that i need to have Xcode open. Then the device stayed connected. Maybe it helps you.

Comment: Do you have any native code calling into the .js like on a timer or anything?  Saw weird issue when debugging on chrome that this reminds me of.  When ever native called called into .js whatever the debugger was doing was tossed and things just moved on.

Comment: This is happening for me on an iPhone 6 with iOS 11.3.1. I'm seeing in the console for the iPhone: `EXC_RESOURCE -> webinspectord[1927] exceeded mem limit: ActiveSoft 20 MB (non-fatal) ... 106227.678 memorystatus: killing_highwater_process pid 1927 [webinspectord] (highwater 14) - memorystatus_available_pages: 30853`. Not sure what to do about it though.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a [global hotkey](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph6889?locale=en_US):

1. Go to `System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` -> `App Shortcuts`.
2. Add a hotkey, whatever keys you want (e.g. `Cmd + Alt + I`) and match that hotkey to your cordova’s main html file (e.g. `index.html`).
3. Launch Cordova App.
4. Open Safari WI & close it.
5. Re-launch Safari WI with quick hotkey shortcut set above.
6. Close & re-open cordova app, Safari WI should keep debugging.

Also, as stated in comments, try keeping Xcode open.